# ipad/iphone deployment to device via monotouch

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, mono, xamarin.ios

I have built 2 apps: one for iPhone, one for iPad. They both build perfectly fine and run within the simulator. They also ran fine on the device prior to updating to Xcode 4.3.2.
When I build to the device with MonoTouch, I get this message:

```
Please ensure your device is connected...  
Connected to: Steve’s iPad  
Initializing file service...  
Uploading application  
Finalizing file service...   
Installing application  
Installation failed: AMDeviceInstallApplication returned: 0xe8008017  
The application was terminated by a signal: SIGHUP
```

When I look at the console via Xcode/Organizer I see the following messages:

```
Apr  4 10:22:22 unknown installd[819] <Error>: libMobileGestalt loadBasebandMobileEquipmentInfo: CommCenter error: 1:45  
Apr  4 10:22:22 unknown installd[819] <Error>: libMobileGestalt copyInternationalMobileEquipmentIdentity: Could not get mobile equipment info dictionary  
Apr  4 10:22:22 unknown com.apple.mobile.lockdown[17] <Notice>: Could not receive size of message  
Apr  4 10:22:22 unknown lockdownd[17] <Error>: 010f4000 handle_connection: Could not receive USB message #6 from Xcode. Killing connection  

Apr  4 10:22:23 unknown installd[819] <Error>: 2ffa4000 verify_signer_identity: Could not copy validate signature: -402620393  
Apr  4 10:22:23 unknown installd[819] <Error>: 2ffa4000 preflight_application_install: Could not verify executable at /var/tmp/install_staging.5kF0E7/EastmaniPad.app  
Apr  4 10:22:23 unknown installd[819] <Error>: 2ffa4000 install_application: Could not preflight application install  
Apr  4 10:22:23 unknown mobile_installation_proxy[818] <Error>: handle_install: Installation failed  
Apr  4 10:22:23 unknown com.apple.mobile.lockdown[17] <Notice>: Could not receive size of messageCould not receive size of message  
Apr  4 10:22:23 unknown lockdownd[17] <Error>: 2fff5000 handle_connection: Could not receive USB message #7 from mtouch. Killing connection  
Apr  4 10:22:23 unknown lockdownd[17] <Error>: 2fef1000 handle_connection: Could not receive USB message #14 from mtouch. Killing connection  
Apr  4 10:22:23 unknown installd[819] <Error>: 2ffa4000 handle_install: API failed  
Apr  4 10:22:23 unknown installd[819] <Error>: 2ffa4000 send_message: failed to send mach message of 71 bytes: 10000003  
Apr  4 10:22:23 unknown installd[819] <Error>: 2ffa4000 send_error: Could not send error response to client
```

Has anyone else had this issue, or is there anyone out there who is better equipped to decipher the above stack trace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The crucial part is this:

```
Could not copy validate signature: -402620393
```

If you google this error, you will find a number of ideas:

- Delete the app manually from the device first, then try to upload again.
- Ensure that the provisioning profiles are configured correctly in Xcode. This usually means delete them all and download them again.

I can also throw in a couple ideas of my own:

- Check if the same thing happens to a new project from a template. If that works, there is something in your app that's causing the signature validation to fail.
- Check if the same thing happens to a new Xcode project (and if it works, try again with your project; Xcode is know to do some automatic configuration in some cases)
- Reboot your device and Mac.
- If you have another device, try there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but it turned out to be caused by the Project Options "Executable" setting being set to "**Executable with GUI**" rather than "**Executable**"